# QuickAction by Lorensius

Tags: android, quickaction

I'm attempting to removed the deprecated code `getWidth();` from this code before going to production. I've tried a few of the ways mentioned here at stack for other classes but cannot seem to get it to work for this. Anyone know i can get the with here?

```
public class QuickAction extends PopupWindows implements OnDismissListener {
...
public void show (View anchor) {
    int screenWidth     = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what have you tried so far, but you could use this:

```
 final int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
 Display display = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
 int screenWidth;
 if (version >= 13) {
     Point size = new Point();
     display.getSize(size);
     screenWidth = size.x;
 }
 else {
     screenWidth = display.getWidth();
 }
```

Like javaDoc says method `display.getWidth()` was deprecated in API level 13 so you should use  `display.getSize(Point)` instead.

In case you don't like "magic" numbers, instead of 13 you can use `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2`.

Comment: The method getWindowManager() is undefined for the type QuickAction

Comment: You already have variable mWindowManager in your code. Sorry, I will edit my answer.